# Mining Monero using CPU and GPU at the same time on linux mint cinnamon edition

Tags: graphics

I am trying to mine Monero using my GPU I got xmrig working for my CPU just fine. the issue is with xmrig-nvidia.

before i could install xmrig-nvidia i had to install cuda. then i proceeded to install xmrig-nvidia
https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig-nvidia/wiki/Ubuntu-Build this is a link to the guide i was using.
the whole process went smoothly until i got to the very last step which is the "make" command i got this error

nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_20'
CMake Error at xmrig-cuda_generated_cuda_extra.cu.o.Release.cmake:220 (message):
Error generating
/home/y/xmrig-nvidia/build/CMakeFiles/xmrig-cuda.dir/src/nvidia/./xmrig-cuda_generated_cuda_extra.cu.o

if anybody knows how to resolve this please let me know. My Goal is to mine Monero using my GPU. so if you have a different solution for me that doesn't involve xmrig i'm open to it as long as it works on linux mint.